# error in electron while accessing variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

the below is the error I am getting when I run this code:

on widows 10 and electron Version :8.2.1

Please help

```
wc.on('context-menu', (e, params) => {

    let selectedText = params.selectionText

    wc.executeJavaScript(`alert("${selectedText}")`)
```

the error is:
Javascript error.
alert Not defined

Comment: why you put alert inside ' ' ?

Comment: @SumanKumarDash, they're calling [`webContents.executeJavaScript`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture), which takes in a string of JS code as a parameter.

Comment: I see, Thanks Erick

Comment: its resolved. should not be using" " . Thanks